# how to force use of int $0x80 instead of sysenter for syscall detection

Tags: linux, kernel, x86-64, virtualization, system-calls

I am trying to accomplish project which transition a ELF binary into virtual machine to provide a process its own execution environment similar to http://dune.scs.stanford.edu/. Many papers say "we detect system call...." but did not provide the details of detection except this paper whose code detect the syscall in vmx non root ring 0. (as process will run in this ring). But I am incompetent enough to grasp his method due to lack of documentation and hints in his paper.
The relevant piece of code is as below

```
/*
 * macro to switch to G0 fs.base
 *
 * NOTE: clobbers %rax, %rdx, and %rcx
 */
    .macro SET_G0_FS_BASE
    movq    $0, %gs:IN_USERMODE
    movq    %gs:KFS_BASE, %rax
    movq    %gs:UFS_BASE, %rdx
    cmp %rax, %rdx
    je  1f
#if USE_RDWRGSFS
    wrfsbase %rax
#else
    movq    %rax, %rdx
    shrq    $32, %rdx
    movl    $MSR_FS_BASE, %ecx
    wrmsr
#endif /* USE_RDWRGSFS */
1:
    .endm  


__dune_syscall:
    /* handle system calls from G0 */
    testq $1, %gs:IN_USERMODE
    jnz 1f
    pushq   %r11
    popfq
    vmcall
    jmp *%rcx

1:
    /* first switch to the kernel stack */
    movq    %rsp, %gs:TMP
    movq    %gs:TRAP_STACK, %rsp

    /* now push the trap frame onto the stack */
    subq    $TF_END, %rsp
    movq    %rcx, RIP(%rsp)
    movq    %r11, RFLAGS(%rsp)
    movq    %r10, RCX(%rsp) /* fixup to standard 64-bit calling ABI */
    SAVE_REGS 0, 1
    movq    %gs:TMP, %rax
    movq    %rax, RSP(%rsp)

    /* then restore the CPL0 FS base address */
    SET_G0_FS_BASE

    /* then finally re-enable interrupts and jump to the handler */
    sti
    movq    %rsp, %rdi /* argument 0 */
    lea dune_syscall_handler, %rax
    call    *%rax

    /* next restore the CPL3 FS base address */
    SET_G3_FS_BASE

    /* then pop the trap frame off the stack */
    RESTORE_REGS 0, 1
    movq    RCX(%rsp), %r10
    movq    RFLAGS(%rsp), %r11
    movq    RIP(%rsp), %rcx

    /* switch to the user stack and return to ring 3 */
    movq    RSP(%rsp), %rsp
    sysretq

.globl __dune_syscall_end
__dune_syscall_end:
    nop
```

My questions are as follows

1) How above piece of code is working? Any explanation, pointer or reference will be helpful

2) Any other method to detect system call in this scenario can be possible? I think tweaking with `vdso` will be other solution. What can i think is to force syscall in vmx non root to use `int 80h` and hook this interrupt. Please share Any suggestion for this hack.

Comment: I haven't read the whole question yet, but yeah building the kernel to export an `int 0x80` stub in the `vdso` instead of a `sysenter` stub should be totally transparent to glibc.  Have you looked into the mechanism `strace(1)` uses for tracing system calls?  I'm not sure how it works under the hood, but I do know it's based on the `ptrace(2)` system call, the same one which lets `gdb` control another process for single-stepping.  There's also `ltrace(1)` which uses shared-lib hacks to traces all function calls into shared libs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to explain you this piece of code (would need to have more than that but i can't because the git repository is not still available)

But detecting system call in vmx non root rely on some tricks you can find in this [paper](https://www.sec.in.tum.de/assets/staff/pfoh/PfohSchneider2011a.pdf), page 6 and 7.
basically, to detect

- syscall/sysret: you have to disable CSE bit in your EFER so that any attempt to use syscall/sysret would result invalid opcode exception that you will intercept
- sysenter/sysexit: you have to save the SYSENTER_CS_MSR somewhere in the hypervisor, then load it with a null value so that any use of sysenter/sysexit would result in a general protection exception that you will catch